# PHP passing variable in __construct of a class

Tags: php

ive browsed many articles here but I just can't make this work for the life of me.

```
class Database{

    private $host;

    function __construct( $vhost = ''){
        $this->host = $vhost == '' ? db_host : $vhost;
    }

    function connect(){
        echo "Host: ".$this->host;
    }
}
```

I've omitted some unnecessary code but it's same concept.
I get "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context" when trying to echo. What am I missing here?

Comment: how are your calling this function `connect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably call `Database::connect()` instead of `$somevar->connect()`. You can't refer to this in static context indeed.

Comment: this is how i call it:

$d = new Database(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name);
$d::connect();

Comment: @user Double colon is for static (not instance) access. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: No because there is no instantiated object constructed, therefore construct is never called.

Comment: You,re welcome. @thenetimp, if you look at the first comment, you will see that it is constructed. But it doesn't help much.